# How to pass a parameter in such scenario

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Say tp0 is the lowest hierarchy, all real code omitted just leave a parameter

```
module tp0;
parameter num=0;
endmodule
```

Where it is instanced

```
module tp
(
input id
);
//what I want to do is below code, but this will not pass compile since parameter need this is a constant!

tp0 #(id) tp_i();

endmodule
```

**id** is an input but this is actually be assign as fixed value in tp's instance.

```
module tb
.....
tp tp_0
(
 .id(0)
);

tp tp_1
(
 .id(1)
);
....
endmodule
```

How to resolve this if the pass of **id** is such a way and need to be passed into a parameterized module tp0?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Verilog is a RTL language, which means that you are describing hardware that will be eventually synthesized.

- When you use a parametrized instance, the parameter is analyzed at compile time and that affects how in synthesis the code will be transformed. The parameter *NUM* (capital letters suggested for params) usually refers to number of bits or instances, thus it needs to be known to calculate for example how many flip-flops should be instanced.
- An input is something that dynamically changes while the application is running (ASIC or FPGA), thus it cannot be defined at compile time by connecting it to a parameter.

In your case, the best solution is to add a parameter also to *tp* module and then connect it to *tp0.NUM*, but it is not clear from this example what is your target or if this code is for simulation only (various quick alternatives) or if needs to be synthesized.

---

An elaborate alternative might be that in *tp* module you instance two submodules with each value of the parameter (0 and 1) and then mux the outputs depending on the value of *id*.

```
module tb();
    tp tp0 (.id('0));
    tp tp1 (.id('1));
endmodule

module tp(
    input logic id
);
    logic out0, out1, out_f;

    tp_sub #(0) tp_0(.out(out0));
    tp_sub #(1) tp_1(.out(out1));

    always_comb begin
        if (id) begin
            out_f = out1;
            //or other things
        end
        else begin
            out_f = out0;
            //or other things
        end
    end

endmodule
```